# Create mixed groups from large amount of data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with data like this:

```
Row     Group       Amount
1       Group A     20
…       Group A     20
3000    Group A     20
3001    Group B     20
…       Group B     20
6000    Group B     20
6001    Group C     20
…       Group C     20
9000    Group C     20
```

And I want to order this data, like this:

```
Row     Group       Amount
1       Group A     20
2       Group B     20
3       Group C     20
4       Group A     20
5       Group B     20
6       Group C     20
7       Group A     20
8       Group B     20
9       Group C     20
…               
9000    GroupC      20
```

How can I do this?
I was thinking that maybe using a Windows function, but can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this logic ?

1. you want groups of 3 lines A, B, C that need to be ordered somehow,
2. within these groups ordering is simple A, then B, then C

Therefore you want to give each line the number of group it should belong to.
To do so:

- separate the rows per group (A, B or C),
- give each row a number
- order all the rows in that number, then per group..

In SQL it gives:

```
SELECT
  `Group`,
  amount
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY ROW),
  `Group`
```

with some sample data it returns indeed:

[image]

To further illustrate the effect of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY ROW) AS new_row,
  `Group`,
  amount
FROM
  sample
ORDER BY
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY ROW),
  `Group`
```

returns

[image]